# project euler #10. getting wrong answer

Tags: c

i wrote the following code for the euler's project problem 10. Although am getting the correct numbers of prime numbers(as checked by the code given in a similar question) but the sum output is coming incorrect
the code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define upper 2000000
int main(void)
{
   bool prime[upper];
    long long sum=0, i,k;
    for(i=0;i<upper;i++)
    {
        prime[i]=true;
    }
    for(i=2;i<upper;i++)
    {
        if(prime[i])
        {

            for(k=2;i*k<upper;k++)
            {
                prime[k*i]=false;
            }
        }
    }
    long count=0;
    for(i=2;i<upper;i++)
    {
        if(prime[i])
        {
            count++;
            sum +=i;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d",count,sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This project goal is to let you solve problems from your own to learn ;-)

Comment: It would also help if you post the output you get and the one you expect.

Comment: You've told a story. You forgot to ask a question. What's your question?

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%d %d",count,sum);
```

is your problem. The sum gets calculated correctly but you use the wrong format string. Check the printf format, especially what you need to output a long long.